# Как отследить изменение стиля у элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<textarea class="description"  name="text" style="display: none;">
</textarea>
```

меняется на

```
<textarea class="description"  name="text" style>
</textarea>
```

Как можно отследить это изменение?

Comment: А зачем это необходимо?

Comment: для запуска некоторых команд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683311/1597497), используя [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        console.log('style changed!');
    });    
});

var target = document.getElementById('myId');
observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

, где [MutationRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683311/1597497) будет содержать в себе старый и новый стили.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.
А не подскажите как отслеживать по классу?
На странице есть несколько нужных элементов, которые нужно отслеживать.
Пробовал вместо getElementById использовать getElementsByClassName. Но это не помогло

Comment: Так возвращается ж массив. об console.log() его ж видно. Проходись по элементам этого массива. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: спасибо.  В конечном итоге остановился на этом:

`document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(targetNode => { 
  observer.observe(targetNode, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
    });`